# How do I fix "Unable to download app" error on iOS 10?

Tags: applications

Recently, i've been unable to download a single app that I have already purchased on my iPad. I've tried the DNS 8.8.8.8, time and date, hard reset, sign out and in, nothing has worked. Any suggestions?
My device is not on cellular, it is not jailbroken. Every time I try to download this app, it says "Unable to download this app at this time"

Comment: What error messages are you getting?  Is your device jailbroken?  Have you verified your Apple ID & password are correct?  Is this on wifi or cellular?  Your question is missing a lot of info that we would need in order to help you with an answer.  Please see [ask] for guidance on good info to include.

Comment: I have verified my apple ID and password are correct, and I am signed in.

Comment: This is one particular app? Do other apps install? Could the app in question now not be supported by iOS 10?

Comment: Other apps do install, it is supported by iOS 10.

Comment: Is that one app still available in the App Store?  Was it originally installed using same Apple ID that you're trying now?  It's possible the app is no longer available or not available to the Apple ID you're using.

Comment: Yes, yes. I'm still using the same Apple ID